# Excel VBA Userform – Textbox date calculations: Date +value=Expiry Date

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform, date-arithmetic

Thank you for checking out my query.

I’m developing a form where the user enters the Start Date in TXT_StartDate and will select an option from a combobox (Cmbox_CardType) that gets the value based on selection from a table on a worksheet called ‘Validation List’ with a named range (TBL_Card_Type).

For example:

User types in Start Date in the textbox (TXT_StartDate), and then selects from the combo box(Cmbox_CardType) the type of card issued, depending on the option, the number of days to be added to the Start Date and then in another textbox (TXT_CARD_ExpiryDate) it should calculate the expiry date, based on column 3 of the named range,  excluding weekends and public holidays.

The dropdown values are taken from the worksheet named 'Validation Lists' and is located B2:D7, with the number in column D (number represents number of days for the particular option)

Table headings of the worksheet "Validation Lists": 
**"Card Type Code"**, **"Card Type Description"** ,**"Period of Days"**

***Control Names:***

TXT_StartDate

Cmbox_CardType (based on Validation List (sheet with Named range of card type

Named range: TBL_Card_Type (B2:D7)

TXT_CARD_ExpiryDate

Date format for textboxes and sheet cells: dd/mm/yyyy

The data from the controls would then be passed into the “Visitor Card Log Sheet”

I’ve looked at various forums, tutorials etc, but haven’t found any that I could successfully adapt to my needs. I have been working on this for some time without success, would anyone have a solution that will do what I require?

I'm sorry if it sounds a bit confusing.

Any assistance greatly appreciated. 
Cheers,
TheShyButterfly